# A set of struct with different == and < operator semantic

Tags: c++, stl, set

I am using a very simple structure, mapping, as defined below:

```
struct mapping{
    int code;
    string label;

    bool operator<(const mapping& map) const {
        return code < map.code;
    }

    bool operator==(const mapping& map) const {
        return label.compare(map.label) == 0 ;
    }
};
```

I would like to create a set of mapping ordered by their code. For that, I have overloaded the < operator. It works fine. I can insert some mappings with different labels without any problem.

The problem come when I try to insert mappings with the same code but different label. Actually, in the second step of the process, I have no idea if a mapping with same label has been previously inserted. So, I need to call the find() function to determine if it is the case or not. If no mapping with same label has been inserted, it is ok, I just need to insert this new one (but its code will be temporarily the same than one other mapping). If one mapping with the same labels exists, I just need to update its code. I though that overloading the == operator as I did should be enough but it is not the case as illustrated by the following code.

```
mapping m = {1,"xxx"};
mapping m2 ={1, "yyy"};

this->fn[0].insert(m);

set<mapping>::iterator itTmp;
itTmp = this->fn[0].find(m2);
if (itTmp != this->fn[0].end() ) {
    cout << "m2 exists "<<endl;

    if ( !(*itTmp == m2) ){
        cout << "But it is different according to the definition of the == operator "<<endl;
    }
}
```

Associated output is:

```
m2 exists
But it is different according to the definition of the == operator
```

How can I solve this issue and manage to deal with operators < and == with very different semantics? Ideally, I would like to avoid iterating on the whole set to look for mapping with the same label. Complexity of such a strategy is O(n) and n can be quite huge in my application. Similarly to the complexity of find() I would prefer a solution in O(log n).

Thanks,

Yoann

Comment: BTW, operator<() should be used to define that an object is actually smaller than an other object (is a mapping really smaller because mapping::code is smaller?).  If you need to sort a set based on another order, it is better to pass the ordering as template parameter: `std::set<mapping, SpecialOrdering> specialOrderedSet`

Comment: @stefaanv So `std::string("that")` is smaller than `std::string("this")`?  And a `std::set<int>` containing 1 and 10 is smaller than one containing just 2?

Comment: @aschepler: yes, apparently, even though for a set that doesn't make much sense.  You seem to disagree with what I wrote, but I'm not sure what you mean.  My point is that if you use operator<() just to sort a set, then you can't use another operator<() if you need another order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a class can reasonably be sorted by more than one of its fields, it should not have relational operators (excepting `operator==` and `operator!=`) at all.

Yes, `std::map` and `std::set` by default use `std::less` as the comparator (which uses `operator<` internally), but that's just convenience so you don't need to write a function object just to create a `set<double>`, where `double` has one canonical sort order (and therefore defines a (built-in) `operator<`).

They also offer a comparator template argument, and you can and should use it to provide exactly the indexing that you need for that container (like a relational database). There are also containers (in boost) that maintain more than one index for a set of elements.

As an example, consider a `point2d` class:

```
struct point2d { int x, y; };
```

One could reasonably want to index a container of `point2d`s by either `x` or `y`, so following the above, `point2d` shouldn't define an `operator<` at all. To avoid having every user of the class inventing their own sorting function objects, they can be supplied together with `point2d`:

```
struct less_point2d_by_x {
    typedef bool result_value;
    // the mixed overloads are for use in std::lower_bound and similar
    bool operator()( int lhs, int rhs ) const { return lhs < rhs; }
    bool operator()( int lhs, point2d rhs ) const { return lhs < rhs.x; }
    bool operator()( point2d lhs, int rhs ) const { return lhs.x < rhs; }
    bool operator()( point2d lhs, point2d rhs ) const { return lhs.x < rhs.x; }
};
// same for _y
```

Usage:

```
std::vector<point2d> v = ...;
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), less_point2d_by_x()); // sort by x
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), less_point2d_by_y()); // sort by y

std::set<point2d, less_point2d_by_x> orderedByX;
std::set<point2d, less_point2d_by_y> orderedByY;
```

If you're not afraid of templates, you can even templatise the relational operator, like this:

```
template <template <typename T> class Op=std::less>
struct point2d_by_x {
    typedef bool result_value;
    // the mixed overloads are for use in std::lower_bound and similar
    bool operator()( int lhs, int rhs )         const { return Op<int>()(lhs, rhs); }
    bool operator()( int lhs, point2d rhs )     const { return Op<int>()(lhs, rhs.x); }
    bool operator()( point2d lhs, int rhs )     const { return Op<int>()(lhs.x, rhs); }
    bool operator()( point2d lhs, point2d rhs ) const { return Op<int>()(lhs.x, rhs.x); }
};
// same for _y
```

Usage:

```
std::vector<point2d> v = ...;
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), point2d_by_x<std::less>()); // sort ascending by x
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), point2d_by_x<>()); // same
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), point2d_by_x<std::greater>()); // sort descending by x
// find the position where a `point2d` with `x = 14` would go in the ordering:
std::lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), 14, point2d_by_x<std::greater>());

std::set<point2d, point2d_by_x<std::less> > increasingXOrder;
std::set<point2d, point2d_by_y<std::less> > increasingYOrder;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this very clear and helpful reply. I have learned a lot from it.

Comment: @YoannPitarch: the StackOverflow way to show your appreciation is to upvote answers. I appreciate the kind words, though :)

Comment: The point is I cannot upvoting your reply since I am a newbie and do not have 15 reputation.

Answer (score 1):

As @PiotrNycz pointed out, `std::set` doesn't use or care about `operator==` at all, only `operator<`.  This includes the `std::set<X>::find` member.  So your `find` call is locating an element with the same code, not one with the same label.

But the namespace-scope function `std::find` does use `operator==`, and not `operator<`.

```
itTmp = std::find(this->fn[0].begin(), this->fn[0].end(), m2);
```

Since your `set` is ordered by code, not label, finding an element with given label can't be done as efficiently as finding one with given code when the number of elements is big.  If this matters, other answers have given suggestions on how you might change your container type to help.

Comment: Ok, thanks. It is very useful. By "cannot be done as efficiently as finding one with given code", did you mean that the search time complexity is linear on the number of records?

Comment: Exactly. `std::set<X>::find` is O(log(N)) and `std::find` is O(N), where N is the total number of elements.

Answer (score 0):

`std::set` uses `operator<`, so you'll need to insert the semantics of your `operator==` into `operator<`. You can do this by eg first checking the `code`, and if that is equal, compare the `label`.

---

**UPDATE** The ordered containers in the Standard Library must use comparators that imply a strict weak order. This means that `operator<` needs to deduce a strict order (different elements have a different order), but weak, as it knows nothing about inequality.

In your case, as pointed out in the comments, you will need a comparison of the `string` `label`. Two options:

```
return code < map.code || (!(map.code < code) && label < map.label);
```

or the other way around, in which first you check `label` and then `code`.

Checking only for equality of `label` will break the "strict" sense of ordering.

Comment: Unfortunately, modifying the operator< semantic by "return (code < map.code && label != map.label);" does not solve the problem.

Comment: @YoannPitarch: _Compare_ the `label`, not check for inequality. The `operator<` implementation in your comment does not define a strict ordering.

Comment: @rubenvb I might be stupid but...what is the difference? In my mind, comparing labels means evaluationg if strings are the same.

Comment: e.g. `return code < map.code || (!(map.code < code) && label < map.label);`. Your implementation is not transitive. Consider {1, "a"} < {2, "b"} < {3, "a"} but {1, "a"} !< {3, "a"}.

Answer (score 0):

If you want O(log n) on finding either code or map, then `std::set` is not the right container because this only sorts on one order.  What you need is a double map with as value a pointer to the entry in the other map.  This way, each member is a key in its map and can be found in O(log n).

If you can use boost, check [boost.bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html)

Comment: Looks to be a very nice idea. Thx!! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should create several containers (two or three).
For example:

```
std::list<mapping> storage; // actual storage
std::multiset<mapping*, compare_by_code_functor> by_code; // sorted by code
std::set<mapping*, compare_by_label_functor> by_label; // sorted by label
```

or

```
std::list<mapping> storage; // actual storage
std::multiset<std::list<mapping>::iterator, compare_by_code_functor> by_code; // sorted by code
std::set<std::list<mapping>::iterator, compare_by_label_functor> by_label; // sorted by label
```

Comment: Looks working but not really the most efficient solution from a storage point of view. Hope it exists a better and more elegant solution. But thx anyway.